# Webform Input Field in E164 Format

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I have a field in a webform that posts to a CRM. My issue is that, I need the field to automatically post +1 in the phone number. I need to be able to send SMS from the CRM. It could be hidden. Here's the code to the Webform I'm using. Notice I included the +1 in the pattern. It works good, but I don't want to let user figure out what needs to be done in order to submit information. Please advice and thanks in advance.

```html
<input 
  type="tel"  
  placeholder="Mobile*"   
  pattern="[+]{1}[1]{1}[0-9]{10}"   
  style= "float:left;"  
  oninput="this.className = ''" 
  name="mobile" 
  data-label="" 
  value="" required="yes"
>
```

Comment: Add it to the field value via JavaScript then, the moment the form gets submitted.

Comment: Thanks. My issue is that I don't know exactly how to do it with java...:)